# String.concat() doesn't do concatenation

Tags: java, android, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a String with an int and char including spaces, but not getting any concatenation. What is the reason?

```
private String messages;
Random r = new Random();
int random = r.nextInt(1000);

char ch='s';
messages.concat(String.valueOf(random));
messages.concat(" ");
messages.concat(String.valueOf(ch));
messages.concat(" ");
```

Comment: You need to reassign the return value of `concat()`. `String` is immutable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`concat` does not alter the invoking strings, but returns a new one.

You may assign each resulting `String` to your result like this.-

```
messages = messages.concat(String.valueOf(random));
messages = messages.concat(" ");
messages = messages.concat(String.valueOf(ch));
messages = messages.concat(" ");
```

Or just use the overloaded operator `+`

```
messages = String.valueOf(random) + " " + String.valueOf(ch) + " ";
```

Comment: how can I concat any specified string at the beginning of the string?

Comment: @Martin `messages = "newstring" + messages`

Comment: @Martin Call it the other way around. `"yourString".concat(message);` if you want to use a method call.

Comment: Using the `+` operator again, something like `resultingString = specifiedString + originalString`

Comment: Note: the '+' operator usage will actually use a StringBuilder

Comment: String.valueOf is really not needed, something like: "" + random + " " + ch + " "

Answer (score 11):

`Strings` are immutable. You can either append the result using `String` concatenation as shown in other answers or you can use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```
StringBuilder messages = new StringBuilder();
messages.append(String.valueOf(random));
messages.append(" ");
messages.append(String.valueOf(ch));
messages.append(" ");
```

Have a look at [How do I concatenate two strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java)

---

*Edit:* (to insert at beginning of `String`)

```
messages.insert(0, "newstring");
```

Comment: is there any way by which i can append any specified string at the beginning of the string?

Comment: yes, `StringBuilder` has an [insert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert-int-java.lang.CharSequence-) method with an offset position

Answer (score 6):

A better way is :

```
Random r = new Random();
    int random = r.nextInt(1000);

StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(random));

str.append("s")
str.append(String.valueOf(random))
str.append(" ");
str.append(String.valueOf(ch));
```

Comment: thats better yes, since you wont need to create all those string Objects throw concat() method

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. StringBuilder doesn't alloc a new string for every addition. Any time you're concat'ing more than 2 strings it's the way to go

Answer (score 2):

```
messages += String.valueOf(random) + " " + String.valueOf(ch) + " ";
```

Comment: Would require to initialize `messages` to "" in its declaration

Comment: Yes, this assumes that messages is initialized. The question was about concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

```
char ch='s';
messages =  messages.concat(String.valueOf(random));
messages = messages.concat(" ");
messages = messages.concat(String.valueOf(ch));
messages = messages.concat(" ");
```

String should be RE-Assigned, when you edit a String object, you create a new String Object in the String constant pool, but you didnt assign this new String value to any reference variable, so you will need to re-assign your modifications to the SAME REFERENCE VARIABLE that created them