# Concatenate multiple variables in java

Tags: java, concatenation

Hi im new in java and tried to make this piece of code to work but i can't concatenate the variables

```
public class peces {
        public static void main(String args[]){
        String raza = "Barracuda";
        String alimento = "otros peces";
        int peso = "20";
        System.out.println ("El Peso de la" +raza "es de " +peso "kg y se alimenta de " +alimeto);
        }
}
```

Comment: You're not concatenating enough.

Comment: You've missed out `+` after `raza` and `peso`.

Comment: are you coding in notepad? Any (even quite stupid) IDE would show you some red markings near the obvious syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `+` before each value you add, so a `+` after `raza` (not just before), `peso` and so on.

Thats how string concatenation works in Java.

Like this:

```
System.out.println ("El Peso de la" + raza + "es de " + peso + "kg y se alimenta de " + alimeto);
```

**See**

- [How do I concatenate two strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html