# Grab WebElement text to build a String

Tags: java, string

I want to build a `String` from text that I've grabbed from `WebElements` using `WebDriver`.

```
public String getTextFromWebElements() {
    String stringOne= null;
    List<WebElement> listOfWebElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".events-stuff-morestuff"));
    for (WebElement we : listOfWebElements) {
        stringOne= we.getText();
    }
    return stringOne;
}
```

I want `stringOne` to build a `String` containing a concatenated list of all the text from the `WebElements`, not the last one in the loop (as it does currently). Then I will split them out in the code which calls this method, so I can do an `Assertion` against data from an `API`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate two strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You problem is you override `stringOne` value each iteration: `stringOne= we.getText();`
2. [Never concatenate a `String` inside a loop in `Java`, for this use `StringBuilder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java).
3. I used `char COMMA ','` as SEPARATOR for data, but you can use any just replacing it inside loop. Just note you must initialize char with empty value: `char SEPARATOR = '\0';`.

```
public String getTextFromWebElements() {
        StringBuilder stringOne = new StringBuilder();
        List<WebElement> listOfWebElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".events-stuff-morestuff"));
        char SEPARATOR = '\0';
        for (WebElement we : listOfWebElements) {
            stringOne.append(SEPARATOR);              
            stringOne.append(we.getText());
            SEPARATOR = ',';
    }
    return stringOne.toString();
}
```

Comment: Ok, 2 answers which work - thank you both.  Can I ask how to initialise the empty char without getting an 'empty character literal' error?

Comment: @Steerpike sorry, I've written the answer on the fly, just use `String SEPARATOR = ""`  or `char SEPARATOR = '\0';` (empty char value)