# Concatenate String and variable in JOptionPane window

Tags: java

I have the following method in a test environment, I'm trying to attach the variable count "`loginAttempts`"
to the `JOptionPane` window so the user would know how many failed login attempts they've had so far. 
Essentially, I want to concatenate another string and a variable to this line if possible .

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a valid username and a password. You've had ||loginAttempts|| "failed login attempts", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


Here's the method out of the application" 

private void loginButton(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                             
    username = userName.getText();
    password = userPassword.getText();
    if (username.equals(finalusername) && password.equals(finalpassword) && loginAttempts <= 3) {
        loginSuccess = true;
    } else {
        loginSuccess = false;
        loginAttempts = loginAttempts + 1;
    }
    if (loginSuccess) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have successfully logged in", "Success", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
    } else if (loginAttempts > 3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have had 3 failed login attempt, your account has been locked","Locked", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } else if (!loginSuccess) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a valid username and a password", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be like this `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a valid username and a password , failed attempts " + loginAttempts  , "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);` should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java

Comment: So where is the problem? Do you not know how to concatenate strings in Java? (e.g.: using the + operator) Or what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I wasn't sure if concatenation works within  showMessageDialog() Dev.Joel and L.Cabonne provided the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate this way (replace the last else with that ) :

```
    } else if (!loginSuccess) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a valid username and a password, Number of attempts : "+loginAttempts , "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```