# how do I concatenate two lines dynamically using java?

Tags: java, string

How do I concatenate two lines dynamically using java?

```
String s = "HackerRank ";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
//Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String s2 = scan.nextLine();
//concatenates both the strings        
s = s+s2;
// s = s.concat(s2);
System.out.println(s);
scan.close();
```

The output should concatenate two complete lines. for ex. if 
`String s = "Hackerank"` and `String s1 = "is very good to learn coding"`, 
The output should be like:

> Hackerank is very good to learn coding

Comment: Your concatenation looks correct.  Have you tested this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate two strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java)

Comment: `s = s + " " + s2`

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. The code you posted does the concatenation. Are you getting an unexpected result? If so, what?

Comment: please mention the expected outcome and current outcome.

Comment: @TedHopp 
 I had to execute the aforementioned code online on a website called Hackerrank. The output didn't turnout the way I expected.
Expected output: Hackerrank is very good to learn coding.
My output:           Hackerrank

Comment: If that was your output, then you weren't running the code you posted here.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code and it works perfectly may be you don't know how to use it. There is no need to concatenate with blank space first as the previous answer says. Just keep doing as you did it work, look at the screenshot: [image: here is the result I got when I ran you code]

with this code

> ```
> import java.util.Scanner;
> public class test {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         String s = "HackerRank "; //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
>         try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
>             //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
>             String s2 = scan.nextLine(); //concatenates both the strings
>             s = s + s2; // s = s.concat(s2);
>             System.out.println(s);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Please don't post images when text will do just fine.

Comment: A `BufferedReader` would also work (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine() )

Comment: I executed the same code online via Hackerrank. It didn't work there.

Comment: I've never use Hackerrank. I just intallalled JDK and that's all

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything wrong with the code. The strings will be concatenated. But the output will be

> Hackerankis very good to learn coding.

if you want the output to be as you described you should concatenate a white space like

```
s = s + " " + s2;
```

Comment: There already is a space in string `s`, so this is entirely unnecessary.