# Create a new CSV file with java to add a new column

Tags: java

I am looking at the performance of a particular stock over a period of 30 days. I downloaded the data from Yahoo finance which appears as a CSV file. If I would like to create a new column in my dataset to show the daily percentage change between open and close using java [refer to column H as where the output should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvliq.png), how should I do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean "How do I write a CSV file"?

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit your file line-by-line and add a separator character using the [concat()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_concat.htm) function.

Open the file with a [FileReader or BufferedReader](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-open-read-file-java-string-array-list) and then start parsing.

Official Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)

Please see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

With OpenCSV: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

```
public class OpenCSVTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringWriter target = new StringWriter();

        try(CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader("my,test")); 
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(target);) {
            for(String[] line : reader) {
                String[] added = Arrays.copyOf(line, line.length + 1);
                added[added.length-1] = "addition";
                writer.writeNext(added);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println(target.toString());
    }
}
```

You can replace the `StringReader` and `StringWriter` with your input and output. The reader will then iterate through each line in your csv for you. You can make a copy of the original line and add your new column and write it out into the target.

Breakdown of the code:

```
try(CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader("my,test")); 
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(target);) { ... }
```

This is a try-with-resources block. It makes sure that the reader and writer are closed after they are done.

```
for(String[] line : reader) {
     String[] added = Arrays.copyOf(line, line.length + 1);
     added[added.length-1] = "addition";
     writer.writeNext(added);
}
```

This is a standard for loop. The CSVReader implements the `Iterable` interface, which enables us to use it in the for loop directly.

`Arrays.copyOf(line, line.length + 1);` is a function that creates a copy of the array passed to it, but with a new size. Because you want to add a column, we make a copy of the original array `my,test` and add 1 more space at the end of it, where we can then assign the new value to it by doing: `added[added.length-1] = "addition";`

Finally, we just pass that to the writer which will then correctly write the values into the target, in this case a `StringWriter`, in your case likely a file.

Comment: Hi, could you explain what the portion in between the try and catch means? Sorry I have very basic understanding of java

Comment: @avajhelp i have added a detailed explanation. let me know if something is unclear