# How do i space getString words?

Tags: java, android, xml, string

I have the following code, and i want to have a toast message that says "Congratulations nameToasted, you made 5 points!"
but i get "CongratulationsnameToasted, you made5points!".
i have already tried spacing on the strings.xml, but nothing.

```
String pointsInMessage = getString(R.string.congratulations) + nameToasted;
pointsInMessage = pointsInMessage + getString(R.string.you_made);
pointsInMessage = pointsInMessage + pointsPerAnswer;
pointsInMessage = pointsInMessage + getString(R.string.points_string) ;
```

Comment: You should add empty spaces, between concatenations. Even better, use a StringBuilder. As an alternative, you could join an array of strings using a space as the joining character.

Comment: just use `" "` [this is a space] while  concatenations

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3753879/5515060

Comment: See the Formatting Strings section of the [String Resources docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like that:

```
String pointsInMessage = getString(R.string.congratulations) +" "+nameToasted;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `String.format()`, something like following:

```
final String pointsInMessage = String.format("%s %s, %s %d %s!", getString(R.string.congratulations), nameToasted, getString(R.string.you_made), pointsPerAnswer, getString(R.string.points_string));
```

Assuming that *pointsPerAnswer* is an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

getString() always returns the string with .trim() applied so you can't use trailing and leading spaces in the strings.xml file.

Here is an example of a string builder you can use:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(R.string.congratulations).append(" ")
  .append(nameToasted).append(R.string.you_made).append(" ") 
  .append(pointsPerAnswer).append(" ").append(R.string.points_string);
String message = sb.toString();
```

this should give you the message you want to display.