# How to click on image or icon with anchor tag in Selenium

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a script for gmail login and logout.
I have done login successfully.
Now to do Logout, I have to first click on User icon which has Logout button inside it.
I am writing it as below code, but it's not working:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title=Google Account: FirstName LastName   (email@gmail.com)]")).click();
```

Please let me know the solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like "a[title=Google Account: " + firstName  + lastName +
 "(" + eMail + ")]"

firstName, lastName and eMail are String variables. And you should probably use @title, but I'm not very sure.

[Look here a simple example of concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the *User Icon* and then to `click()` on the link with text as **Sign out** you have to induce *WebDriverwait* for the link with text as **Sign out** to be clickable and you can use the following lines of code :

- `cssSelector` :

  ```
  //Click on the image    
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[role=button][title^='Google Account']")).click();
  //Click on Sign out
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[href^='https://accounts.google.com/Logout']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath` :

  ```
  //Click on the image    
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@role='button' and contains(@title,'Google Account') and contains(@href,'https://accounts.google.com/SignOutOptions')]")).click();
  //Click on Sign out
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'https://accounts.google.com/Logout')]"))).click();
  ```