# How to create an engine that prefixes url "http://"?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm currently doing a project using Spring mvc and was working on my backend part.(Dealing with bookmarks) I have created a engine interface (IBookmarkEngine) and then made my implementation (BookmarkEngine). 
I'm just having trouble making this work. How do I create an engine that prefixes url "http://"?

```
 public class BookmarkEngine implements IBookmarkEngine {

     private static final String URL_PREFIX = "http://";

     @Override
     public String getFullUrl(String url) {

         if () {
             return;
         }
         return url;
     }
 }
```

Comment: You're asking how to concatenate strings?

Comment: `return URL_PREFIX + url;` ? Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate two strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can add the prefix if it is not present.  So in your IF statement you can do a `startsWith` search on the url.  If the url does not start with the prefix, then add the prefix to the url.

```
 public class BookmarkEngine implements IBookmarkEngine {

     private static final String URL_PREFIX = "http://";

     @Override
     public String getFullUrl(String url) {

         if (!url.startsWith(URL_PREFIX)) {
             return  URL_PREFIX + url;
         }
         return url;
     }
 }
```