# Get a value from Jtextfield3 from jtextfiled1 and 2

Tags: java, jtextfield

I need to see a value which means if jtextfiled's text is as "abcd" and jtextfield2 text as "efg" I need to see out put as in the 3rd jTextfield as "abcdefg" .

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @TrippKinetics i got codes as "sum " calculates when I done research please help sir

Comment: I need to see your actual source code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate two strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
if(jtextfield.getText().equals("abcd") && jtextfield2.getText().equals("efg"))
{
    jtextfield3.setText("abcdefg");
}
```

Comment: I would guess the OP actually wants `jTextField3.setText(jTextField1.getText()+jTextField2.getText())`, i.e. concatenation.

Comment: That's not what they said, though.