# Pass Java variable to JavascriptExecutor argument for jQuery function

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

Hi I am using selenium webdriver where I try to execute jQuery script by passing java variable to access valid id.

here is the code.

```
int move = 3;
String date = "2011-03-05";
String script = "$('#date_of_birth-'+move+).datepicker('update', '+date+')";
js.executeAsyncScript(script, 1000);
```

I want to use both move and date variable inside jQuery function.

Comment: Hi, what is the source of your confusion? It seems like you are unable to concatenate strings in Java. If that's the case, have a look at this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After long struggles and debugging I found the solution.

here is the right way to pass java variable to jQuery function.

```
String script = "$('#date_of_birth-" + move + "').datepicker('update', '" + date + "')";
```

Comment: You should delete this, I think, since you just copied my answer and made a small change.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the string concatenation to take place within Java itself, then it has to happen *outside* of the intended JavaScript string.  What you are currently doing is to intercalate the literal strings `move` and `date` inside your JavaScript string.

```
String script = "$('#date_of_birth-'" + move + "').datepicker('update', '" + date + "')";
```

But, we can use a `StringBuilder` here which would make things easier to read (and possibly run faster):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
sb.append("$('#date_of_birth-'");
sb.append(move);
sb.append("').datepicker('update', '");
sb.append(date);
sb.append("')");
String script = sb.toString();
```

Comment: still not working :( the script is working without passing java variables `String script = "$('#date_of_birth-1').datepicker('update', '2018-08-15')";` but when I pass variables nothing update on datepicker.

Comment: you edit your answer but it still not working test on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below snippet in your application which may works i guess:-

**Exsisting problem:**
*$('#date_of_birth-'3)*.datepicker('update', '2011-03-05');

**Current solution:**
*$('#date_of_birth-3')*.datepicker('update', '2011-03-05');

snippet:
int move = 3;
        String date = "2011-03-05";

```
    String scripting = "$('#date_of_birth-" + move + "').datepicker('update', '" + date + "')";

    System.out.println(scripting);

    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("");
    sb1.append("$('#date_of_birth-");
    sb1.append(move+"'");

    sb1.append(").datepicker('update', '");
    sb1.append(date);
    sb1.append("')");

    String script1 = sb1.toString();
    System.out.println(script1);
```

Comment: Duplication of my answer.