# How do you concatenate two strings to show in one textview?

Tags: android, string, concatenation

I am working on a Text Adventure Game.

In the strings.xml I have two strings.

How do you add the two strings together so that a textview shows:

You are in a Garage.

Thanks in advance.

strings.xml

```
<string name="location_prefix">You are in a </string>
<string name="location_name">Garage</string>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.textdisplay

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: welcome stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate Strings using the + operator:

```
String firstString = resources.getString(R.string.you_are)
String secondString = resources.getString(R.string.garage)

textView.setText(firstString + secondString)
```

before you ask, always check if someone had similar problem :)

> [How do I concatenate two strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thanks. I am very much a beginner in Android programming. What file do you place the above code in? activity_main.xml?

Comment: In MainActivity.java (java class not xml) which is linked to activity_main.xml

Comment: Where abouts in the above code as I am getting unresolved reference errors on "firststing" and "secondstring" strings.

Answer (score 1):

Assume in activity_main.xml file, there is a TextView whose id is `textView`. Here are some solutions to set text for the `textView`.

**Solution 1**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        textView.text = getString(R.string.location_prefix) + getString(R.string.location_name)
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        textView.text = "${getString(R.string.location_prefix)}${getString(R.string.location_name)}"
    }
}
```

**Solution 3**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        textView.text = String.format("%s%s", getString(R.string.location_prefix), getString(R.string.location_name))
    }
}
```

It's up to you to pick a solution.

**Update:** To keep the end space in location_prefix string, then go to string.xml file and change:

```
<string name="location_prefix">You are in a </string>
```

to

```
<string name="location_prefix">You are in a\u0020</string>
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats great. I went with Solution 1. I had to add "import android.widget.TextView".  However I get the error "Overrides function in AppCompatActivity".

Comment: @seddonac Do you have any problem with your code now?

Comment: The code runs but with a warning as above with "overrides function in appcompatactivity". How do you get rid of the warning?

Comment: Also, how can I add a space between the strings? At the moment the result of concatenating the two strings is "You are in aGarage". I need a space between "a" and "Garage".

Comment: Thanks that works fine. What do you do about the warnings? The app runs fine with no build errors.

Comment: About the warning, please post your gradle file.

Comment: Gradle file as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to concat them in code, you could use this plugin I've created: https://github.com/LikeTheSalad/android-stem which will generate a string with all of the strings you'd like to concatenate at build time, so for your case, you'd have to define the following in your strings:

```
<string name="location_prefix">You are in a ${location_name}</string>
<string name="location_name">Garage</string>
```

And then, when you run the tool, you'd get the following:

```
<!-- Auto generated during compilation -->
<string name="location_prefix">You are in a Garage</string>
```

Which you can then access to as with any other manually defined string within your layouts and/or code.

More details on the repo's page.