# How can i customize date format in Java given inputs

Tags: java

I  want  to write excel file date in  format "dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mm"  an example of  that is
12/03/2022  08:30

The  problem  is  that i have all these values as  parameters..
My  fields stored  in  database are:

```
days : integer
month :  integer
year:integer
time :  float (example  08.00)
```

The goal  is  that i retrieve  all  of  them and  i  want to  combine and  have  a result  of that "dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mm".

Could i combine them  to  create that date format?
I  ask  that because if i write that in excel as string maybe that type will causes problems with excel graphs  etc..

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. Are you asking how to concatenation strings, or parse a date in a given format, or both?

Comment: I will edit my  question  ,  but  i  think that  i want both  of them .

Comment: Both of those questions should be answerable with a minimum of searching, on SO or the web in general.

Comment: @DaveNewton i posted because i cannot find solution till now..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3753878

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4216745

Comment: `08.00` means 8:00. Would 8:30 be given as 8.3 or 8.5?

Comment: `LocalDate.of(2022, 3, 12).atTime(LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(Math.round(8.5 * Duration.ofHours(1).toSeconds()))).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm"))` yields `12/03/2022 08:30`. Break up into more statements. And fill in the values from your database instead of 2022, 3, 12 and 8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you store a single long ("bigint") for the complete time? It is exact down to a millisecond and won't overflow in the next generations. You can get this time using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and use time classes like `Date` / `LocalDateTime`. They've got methods for everything.

---

With your approach:

`hour`:

- Round your `time` towards `0`.

`minute`:

- Subtract `hour` from `time`.

  - Now you've got your `minute` as a value from `0` (inclusive) to `1` (exclusive).
- Multiply it by `60` to get it as a value from `0` (inclusive) to `60` (exclusive).

So the result looks like this:

```
int hour = (int) time;
int minute = (int) ((time - hour) * 60)
String timeString = days + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute;
```